# How to pass all column names in a single string in DataFrame.selectExpr() method in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am passing all columns to userJourney data frame one by one and its working following is the code

var transformedUserJourney: DataFrame = userJourney.selectExpr("userid", "time", "channel")

but how to pass all columns of the Data Frame  in one string like

var str :String = "\"userid \""  +","\"time\""  +  ",\"channel\""

var transformedUserJourney: DataFrame = userJourney.selectExpr(str )

Comment: selectExpr expect a vararg, so just userJourney.selectExpr("userid", "time", "channel"). But select all column doing nothing seems not so useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

- df.columns which is an array[String] with the column names
- the :_* operator (which turns an array into a vararg)

eg.
`city_df.selectExpr( city_df.columns :_* )`

Answer (score -1):

In Java below works:

```
Dataset ds = ds.alias("x");

Dataset ds1 = ds.selectExpr("x.*");
```

x is the alias and you can use x.* similar to SQL syntax.